# Bootstrap Pop-up Modal is not showing up. Instead I get black screen

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, jsp, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I am working on 2 bootstrap modals - Update modal & delete modal.
Update modal is working perfectly fine on click of update button.
But when I click on delete button(same as for update), delete modal doesnt pop-up, instead I get a black screen.
I am struggling on this issue quite long and not able to get the solution for this.
I have tried doing "inspect element" & compare both the modals, but it seems fine to me.
Also, I have found similar queries on SOF but it did not work.
I have add/remove different css & js files in the script tag but still it didn't work for me.
Below is the code :-

**CSS & js links inside head tag :-**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.11/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.2/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

**Update & Delete Buttons to call Modals :-**

```
<td align="center">
<!-- Update Button -->
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" onclick="editEmp(${emp.empid})" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editemp" data-title="Edit"><em class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></em></button>
<!-- Delete Button -->
<button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteemp" data-title="Delete"><em class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></em></button>
</td>
```

**Update Modal :-**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="editemp" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
        aria-labelledby="edit" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content" style="left: -600px" >
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"
                        aria-hidden="true">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    </button>

                </div>
<form:form id = "regForm" action="registerEmp" modelAttribute="empreg">
<!-- some form elements -->
</form:form>
</div>
            <!-- /.modal-content -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
    </div>
```

**Delete Modal**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="deleteemp" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
        aria-labelledby="edit" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content" style="left: -640px;">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"
                        aria-hidden="true">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    </button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title custom_align" id="Heading">Delete this
                        entry</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">

                    <div class="alert alert-danger">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign"></span> Are you
                        sure you want to delete this Record?
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer ">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"></span> Yes
                    </button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> No
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /.modal-content -->
        </div>
```

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: too may jquery links ... remove them and give a try

Comment: @ChandraShekhar :- Still didn't work, i get black & unresponsive screen.

Comment: can you make a fiddle at jsfiddle.net

Comment: @ChandraShekhar :- Yes, i will do & get back

Comment: @ChandraShekhar :- Please use this link for fiddle - 
https://jsfiddle.net/dsolanki/qspjt5u5/

Comment: checkout my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@CoderDS

[Link For Reference](https://jsfiddle.net/DChandraShekhar/b7homhde/2/)

You have missed a closing `div`. This should get your work done.

**Updated HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">

            <div class="panel panel-default panel-table">
              <div class="panel-heading">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col col-xs-6">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">Employee Details</h3>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col col-xs-6 text-right">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary btn-create" onclick="createNew()">Create New</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="panel-body table-responsive">
                <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-list">
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th><em class="fa fa-cog"></em></th>
                        <th class="hidden-xs">Employee Id</th>
                       <th>First Name</th>
                        <th>Last Name</th>
                        <th>Address</th>
                        <th>Country</th>
                        <th>Contact</th>
                        <th>Email</th>
                        <th>Gender</th>
                        <th>Date of Birth</th>
                        <th>Education</th>
                        <th>UserName</th>
                        <th>Password</th>

                    </tr> 
                  </thead>
                  <tbody id="myTable">
<!--                 foreach -->
                     <c:forEach items="${data}" var="emp">
                          <tr>
                            <td align="center">
                              <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" onclick="editEmp(${emp.empid})" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editemp" data-title="Edit"><em class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></em></button>
                              <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" onclick="deleteemp(${emp.empid})" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delemp" data-title="Delete"><em class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></em></button>
                            </td>
                            <td class="hidden-xs">${emp.empid}</td>
                            <td>${emp.firstname}</td>
                            <td>${emp.lastname}</td>
                            <td>${emp.address}</td>
                            <td>${emp.country}</td>
                            <td>${emp.contact}</td>
                            <td>${emp.email}</td>
                            <td>${emp.gender}</td>
                            <td>${emp.dob}</td>
                            <td>${emp.education}</td>
                            <td>${emp.username}</td>
                            <td>${emp.password}</td>

                          </tr>
                       </c:forEach>
<!--                        foreach -->

                        </tbody>
                </table>

              </div>
              <div class="panel-footer">
                <div class="row">

                  <div class="col col-xs-4">Page 1 of 5
                  </div>
                  <div class="col col-xs-8">
                    <ul class="pagination hidden-xs pull-right" id="myPager">
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="pagination visible-xs pull-right">
                        <li><a href="#">«</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">»</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
      <ul class="pagination pagination-lg pager" id="myPager"></ul>
      </div></div>

              </div>
            </div>

</div></div></div>

<div class="modal fade" id="editemp" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
        aria-labelledby="edit" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"
                        aria-hidden="true">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    </button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title custom_align" id="Heading">Employee
                        Details</h4>
                </div>
                <form:form id = "regForm" action="registerEmp" modelAttribute="empreg">
                    <div class="modal-body">
                    <form:hidden path="empid" id="empid"/>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label" for="firstname">Name</label> 
<!--                            <label>First Name</label> -->
                                <form:input path="firstname" id="firstname" class="form-control " type="text"></form:input>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class=" control-label" for="lastname">Last Name</label>
                            <form:input path="lastname" id="lastname" class="form-control "  type="text"></form:input>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class=" control-label" for="address">Address</label>
<!--                            <label>Address</label> -->
                            <form:textarea path="address" id="address" class="form-control " placeholder="Enter Address" type="text"></form:textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">                        
                        <label>Country</label>
                                <form:select path="country" id="country" class="form-control" placeholder="Select your country">
                                    <form:option value="select">Select Your Country</form:option>
                                    <form:option value="India">India</form:option>
                                    <form:option value="USA">USA</form:option>
                                    <form:option value="Australia">Australia</form:option>
                                    <form:option value="England">England</form:option>
                                    <form:option value="Germany">Germany</form:option>
                                    <form:option value="China">China</form:option>
                                    <form:option value="Pakistan">Pakistan</form:option>
                                </form:select>
                            </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label" for="gender">Gender</label>
                            <div class="">
                                <label  class="radio-inline" for="gender-0"> <form:radiobutton
                                        path="gender" name="gender" id="gender-0" value="Male" />
                                    Male
                                </label> <label class="radio-inline" for="gender-1"> <form:radiobutton
                                        path="gender" name="gender" id="gender-1" value="Female" />
                                    Female
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Date of Birth</label>
                                <form:input path="dob" id="dob" class="form-control " placeholder="Enter Date of Birth" type="date"></form:input>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Contact</label>
                    <form:input path="contact" id="contact" class="form-control " placeholder="Enter Mobile/phone number" type="text"></form:input>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">    
                    <label>Email Address</label>
                    <form:input path="Email" id="email" class="form-control " placeholder="xyz@abc.com" type="text"></form:input>
                    <div class="form-group">

                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Education</label>
                        <form:input path="education" id="education" class="form-control " placeholder="Enter highest education" type="text"></form:input>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Username</label>
                        <form:input path="username" id="username" class="form-control " placeholder="Enter username" type="text"></form:input>
                    </div><br><br>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Password</label>
                        <form:password path="password" id="password" class="form-control " placeholder="Enter password" ></form:password>
                    </div>

                    <div class="modal-footer ">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg"
                            style="width: 100%;">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"></span> Update
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </form:form>
            </div>
            <!-- /.modal-content -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
    </div>
  </div>


<div class="modal fade" id="delemp" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
        aria-labelledby="edit" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"
                        aria-hidden="true">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    </button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title custom_align" id="Heading">Delete this
                        entry</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">

                    <div class="alert alert-danger">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign"></span> Are you
                        sure you want to delete this Record?
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer ">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"></span> Yes
                    </button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> No
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /.modal-content -->
        </div>
```

Comment: :-  That worked !! Thank you so much to find the bug. It would have taken me years to get this .